# Is the overall energy conserved in this situation?

Tags: energy-conservation, electrical-resistance, potential-energy, capacitance, dissipation

Imagine a fully charged capacitor.
This will create an electric field, and if a fixed charged particle is nearby, it will possess some amount of electric potential energy.
But what happens to the potential energy if one discharges the capacitor?
The potential energy must be converted into other forms of energy, but I can't understand how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If totally discharged the energy will have been dissipated as heat in cicuit resistance. If partially discharged, part of the energy is dissipated as heat, part stored somewhere else in the circuit, and part retained by the capacitor. In all cases the total energy is conserved.

All circuits have resistance (except supercooled conductors) so when a capacitor discharges at least part of its potential energy is dissipated as resistance heating. If the circuit consists only of resistance, all the energy will be dissipated as heat.

But if there’s other energy storage devices in the circuit some of the discharge energy can be stored in those devices. For example if there are other capacitors in the discharging circuit some of the discharge energy can be stored as electrical potential energy in those other capacitors. If there are rechargeable batteries in the circuit, part of the discharged energy may be stored as chemical potential energy in the batteries. The same would apply to any other electrical energy storage devices.

The above neglects a small amount of electromagnetic energy that may be radiated away from the circuit.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two charges, each has the potential to do work while moving in the field of the other. If you remove either one (to a large distance away), the other no longer has that potential.